# Header in CollectionView not Displaying iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uicollectionview, swift3

I want to add a few buttons to the header of a Collection view. Enabled 'Section Header' from the storyboard. Then dragged a 'view' to that header. And put its background color to green

But I don't why it's not displaying. In the simulator as you see, only a blank space for the header.
[image]

Comment: Have you declared `optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView` in your soure code?

Comment: @ezcoding tried adding that, but giving me error

Comment: @GijoVarghese the actual error message would help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this Method

Give name in `CollectionHeaderCell`

[image]
 [image]

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    switch kind {

    case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:

        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "Header", for: indexPath as IndexPath)

        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue;
        return headerView

    case UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter:
        let footerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "Footer", for: indexPath as IndexPath)

        footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green;
        return footerView

    default:

        assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
    }
}
```

[image]

**// make a cell for each cell index path**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("InviteFriendCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

      let profileimage: UIImageView = (cell.viewWithTag(5) as! UIImageView)

      profileimage.image = UIImage(named:arrayofdata[indexPath.row]["image"]!)
      return cell
 }
```

Comment: Its completely working i have upload screen shot check it . and compare your code and mine one.

Comment: I tried it. Converted all syntax to swift 3. But still it's showing a blank space in header

Comment: Any solution yet?

Comment: @MoazKhan whats your problem bro tell me

Comment: My search bar wasn't visible in the header and after some searching I found that I need to set the header size and it become visible but the main issue is I want to show / hide it based on scroll how should I do that ?

Comment: take one bool varible and when your collectionview scroll at that time change bool value and just do search bar hide and show